# AngularJS ui-date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

So I have :

```
<input ng-model="date1" ui-date>
<div ng-model="date2" ui-date></div>
```

It works great. The div calendar 'date2' will follow the change of its previous ui-date input, namely 'date1' the input box.

AngularUI did a great job, when you have multiple input+div calendars existing in one page, imagine a travel agent booking page, 'date4' will group with 'date3' automatically, 'date6' will group with 'date5' automatically ...etc. well done.

However, in my sample code `<input ng-model="date1" ui-date>` only works in US format with back-slash delimiters 'MM/dd/yyyy'.

My question is, how do I change the default input date format? If I want to have iso-8601 'yyyy-MM-dd' as my input, ui-date doesn't seem to recognise it as a valid input.

I tried `ui-date="yyyy-MM-dd"` it doesn't seem to have any effects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this is a wrapper for the datepicker in jQueryUI, you should check the [document here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

You can set it like this

```
ui-date="{ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }"
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jvbH9Q?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! it helps! How do I know which one is JQuery wrapper or where they are from in AngularUI?